# Sending POST data using the Firefox Request API

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Hello I'd be super grateful for help with this Firefox API question.

I have a webpage listening for a POST variable called sausage:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
<?php   
echo $_POST['sausage'];
?>
```

Using the [Request API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) in the Firefox addon SDK, I've made a button which is supposed to load my webpage while sending the POST variable sausage:

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;

 var button = buttons.ActionButton({
    id: "mozilla-link",
    label: "Visit Mozilla",
    icon: {
        "16": "./icon-16.png",
        "32": "./icon-32.png",
        "64": "./icon-64.png"
        },
    onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state)
{
    tabs.open({
        url: "http://localhost/home.php/",
        onOpen: runScript
    });
}

function runScript(tab)
{
    Request({
      url: "http://localhost/home.php/",
      content: { sausage: 'sausage' }
    }).post();
}
```

This is loading the target page, but not sending the POST variable, so the php echo function throws an error. Please can someone explain what's gone wrong. I especially would like to avoid using any of the lower level API functions because this looks like the kind of job Request should eat for breakfast. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a non-sdk approach you can do it with this: https://github.com/Noitidart/AysncZip/blob/master/bootstrap.js#L515

Comment: maybe you should inspect the raw http request on the server side to see what arrives there. you can also use the [browser toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) to inspect the requests on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

The request api doesn't send the variable when opening the tab, it instead makes a second request to the same url. Check your server logs or the browser console, you should see two requests every time you click that button.

Comment: thank you, I see now that it opens the tab first and so the variable isn't sent when the page is loaded. So how would I change my code so that it sends the POST data at the same time as loads the page? I can easily do this with GET data by sticking it on the end of the url, but that exposes it to the user which is not desirable

Comment: There is no way to do this as far as I know just using the request api. A *hack* around it would be to open a tab with a blank page containing a hidden form that submits as soon as it is loaded. It would create a brief flash but it would work.

Comment: @canuckstani thanks for your help, I've ended up appending the data to the url and using get because it seemed simpler and didn't cause any side effects

Comment: As long as you're guarding against replay, eg you're not altering data on each request, right?

Comment: Right - nothing is being altered, I'm just appending the same variable along with any other GET variables which were already in the url

Comment: ...based on [some code](https://github.com/canuckistani/jp-block-site-example) posted by you in response to a completely different query about blocking websites